# Issue With Redirecting & Query Strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

On our CMS, we use the following piece .htaccess code to serve pages from our CMS:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?slug=$1
```

So the page is served by passing through the slug of the page to index.php

The problem we are having is if you go to this page for example:

http://www.example.com/index.php?slug=contact

You get redirected to this page:

http://www.example.com/?slug=contact

We also have this in our .htaccess to send index.php back to the root:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

What can we do to end up with this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/contact
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:index\.php)?\?slug=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```